# Hibernate @NamedNativeQuery reads stale data written by "normal" entity persist

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, dropwizard

I ran into a slightly strange problem with a Java (Dropwizard) web service that uses Hibernate to read and write to MySQL. The best way I can summarize is that it appears that writes done inside one transaction are not visible to a NamedNativeQuery executed in a second transaction, when both transactions are inside the same session. The writes are visible to an external MySQL client when debugging. When each transaction is in its own session, all the reads see a consistent view of the world. It is almost like the writes make it to MySQL but the NamedNativeQuery is reading from a cached version in memory. I'll try to explain in more detail...

For the purpose of describing this issue, the app has three Hibernate entities which use the same two database tables, let's just say table X and Y and entities A, B and C. Two of the entities (A and B) are simple and map rows in the tables to the entities using methods from `AbstractDAO` ([from Dropwizard](http://www.dropwizard.io/0.7.0/dropwizard-hibernate/apidocs/io/dropwizard/hibernate/AbstractDAO.html#persist-E-)) to read and write but also HQL and the Hibernate Query API. So one row in table X maps to one instance of entity A, one row in table Y maps to an instance of entity B.

The third entity (entity C) is a bit different. It's effectively read-only and is intended to collect some aggregate stats by joining tables X and Y. It uses a `@NamedNativeQuery` to execute a single native MySQL query and map to fields in the entity. This join uses a foreign key on table X that points to table Y.

This is the behavior that I am seeing:

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
ManagedSessionContext.bind(session);

Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

EntityA a = daoA.read(); // reads from table X using HQL query
EntityC c = daoC.read() // reads from X and Y using NamedNativeQuery
a.setFoo(newFoo);
daoA.write(a); // write using AbstractDao.persist. updates table X

tx.commit();

Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
c = daoC.read() // reads X and Y using NamedNativeQuery again. does not see write to table X above^
                // while the app was paused in the debugger here, a MySQL client running the same native query sees the write when selecting from table X
tx.commit();

session.close();
```

This version works:

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
ManagedSessionContext.bind(session);
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

EntityA a = daoA.read();
EntityC c = daoC.read();
a.setFoo(newFoo);
daoA.write(a);

tx.commit();
session.close(); // Each tx has its own session

session = sessionFactory.openSession(); // new session, before only a new tx
ManagedSessionContext.bind(session);
tx = session.beginTransaction();

c = daoC.read() // reads using NamedNativeQuery again. now it DOES see the write above

tx.commit();
session.close();
```

Sorry for obtuse example code... obviously the actual app is more complicated. I don't know much about Hibernate so I hope this is some novice misunderstanding of transactions and sessions. If it turns out this is more complicated and it would be helpful, I can try to extract a minimal example that reproduces the problem and can actually be compiled and run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is hibernate persistenceContext cache, its short circuiting the row -> Object transformation because its already seen the object.

The following will work:

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
ManagedSessionContext.bind(session);

Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

EntityA a = daoA.read();
EntityC c = daoC.read();
a.setFoo(newFoo);
daoA.write(a);
session.flush();
tx.commit();

// This clears the persistenceContext cache and 
// the actionQueue so make sure everything is 
// done before this point.
session.clear(); 

Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
c = daoC.read();
tx.commit();

session.close();
```

Another option could be to use a stateless session, its more useful for bulk operations though.